# Jenkins pipeline polling multiple scm issue

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins pipeline script, which is supposed get 2 repositories from GitLab (triggered by Gitlab webhook), if there are changes on "master" branch in any of the repositories (and so more stuff afterwards). 
My job DSL config:

```
pipelineJob('pipline') {      
      // Enable but do not use SCM polling. This needs to be enabled for
      // notifyCommit to work but we don't want to do any actual polling.
      configure { project ->
        project / 'triggers' << 'hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger' {
          spec('')
        }
      }       
        definition {
            cps {
            sandbox(true)    
            script ('''node('Foo') {
    //repo abc
     checkout changelog: false,
        poll: true,
        scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [
            [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
            disableSubmodules: true,
            parentCredentials: false,
            recursiveSubmodules: false,
            reference: '',
            trackingSubmodules: false],
            [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
            relativeTargetDir: "abc"]
            ],
            submoduleCfg: [],
            userRemoteConfigs: [
            [url: '<repository abc>'],
            [refspec: '+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master'],
            [name: 'origin']
            ]]      
    //repo def
      checkout changelog: false,
        poll: true,
        scm: [$class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
            extensions: [
            [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 20],
            [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
            disableSubmodules: true,
            parentCredentials: false,
            recursiveSubmodules: false,
            reference: '',
            trackingSubmodules: false],
            [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
            relativeTargetDir: "def"],
            [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
            submoduleCfg: [],
            userRemoteConfigs: [
            [url: '<repository def>'],
            [refspec: '+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master'],
            [name: 'origin']
            ]] 
         ...
         do more things
    ''')
       }
      }
    }
```

The polling working fine for the first repository, but when I have changes in a seconds repository not in a master branch, I still get the whole thing started. It looks that it takes last build revision SHA only from the first repository and then uses it to compare in all other repositories.
here's how the git polling log looks like:

```
Started on Feb 15, 2017 12:10:09 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision <SHA from last commit in repository abc on master branch > (refs/remotes/origin1/master)
 > git ls-remote -h <repository abc> # timeout=10
Found 4 remote heads on <repository abc>
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: <SHA from last commit in repository abc on master branch > - already built by 76
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision <SHA from last commit in repository abc on master branch > (refs/remotes/origin1/master)
 > git ls-remote -h <repository def> # timeout=10
Found 2 remote heads on <repository def>
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: <SHA from last commit in repository def on master branch >
Done. Took 1.1 sec
Changes found
```

I was using buildFlowJob before with same functionality and it worked fine.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, and while I don't have a solution, you can track the issue (which others are also having) over here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39621